# Web Page Text Corruption/Character Swap

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I am running into an issue that occurs randomly, but I have been able to reproduce the issue on 3 different desktops. Some other desktops never have this issue and I'm not sure what could be the cause.

All users are running Chrome, and when they pull up certain pages on our web site, the text has been swapped out for completely incorrect text.

Examples: The word "EVENTS" looks like "CT CL RQ" and "MATCHES" says "K ? RAF CQ".

Inspecting the text shows that the text is correct within the element, also refreshing the page will make it show the correct text. However, about 10-20% of the time refreshing will swap it back to the incorrect text on the desktops where the issue is seen.

I don't have enough rep to be able to post an image, but I'm hoping that somebody has seen this before and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Capturing HTML output and sharing that on SO will help!!!! You don't have to post an image.

Also ensure there are no plugins / addons enabled before you try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears to be a Caesar cipher: each character has been moved back 2 in ASCII order. So `C`->`A`, `D`->`B`, `E`->`C`, etc. This also explains the `?`, which is two characters before `A` in ASCII. But I still have no idea why this is happening, or where the spaces came from. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your likely experiencing corrupt characters from how **you copy / pasted** the content from external source; and or **saved your content within a editor with a certain encoding that isn't as optimal**.

• One good method is pop open a classic copy of basic *notepad*  'paste your code / content' in here and **resave**.

• Or **change** your **current** **encoding** settings to `UTF-8` in whatever editor your in > then **resave**.

•  If these aren't helping you try setting the encoding by toggling between the below; see if any resolves your characters - within your actual HTML document via popping one of the below at the top of `<head>`

*this*:  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

*or*: `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text, and by default everything is saved as UTF-8. The headers on the page are set to UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Try the last one then, if first two didn't help resolve ;) answer updated.

Comment: Tested with both, we already had the long version implemented, so I swapped them out and still nothing. The site is http://pvplive.net in case you want to take a look and see if you can reproduce. It's odd that we only have a couple of computers that are having the issue.